# Ubuntu Core zfs tools to mount array?

Tags: ubuntu-core, docker, zfs

I have installed Ubuntu Core bare metal. My intention is to host dockers on it. However I need to mount an existing  ZFS array for data storage. 
Is there a way to get the ZFS tools in an Ubuntu Core instance?

Comment: Not an expert but have a look at this: https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/01/26/lxd-5-easy-pieces

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, but that is for a standard ubuntu install which uses apt. I am using Core which uses snap.